# pre-symplectic and foliation and its trajectories

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $(M,\omega)$, be pre-symplectic, then can we say, we have a foliation of $M$, with tangent spaces $ker\omega$.What can we say about its trajectories. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your definition of pre-symplectic involves constant rank and $\ker\omega$ defines a smooth distribution of hyperplanes in the tangent bundle, then an application of the Frobenious theorem shows that you have a foliation tangent to $\ker \omega$. I'm not sure that one can say more than that in general.

Comment: Seems like a full answer to me. Only obstruction to the characteristic distribution (ker($\omega$) being an honest distribution is that its rank jumps. As Igor says, if this rank is const. , then it is involutive as a distribution.

Comment: Even if the rank is not constant, still the kernel distribution is integrable. I first read this in the unpublished http://www.math.unipd.it/~bottacin/papers/presympred.pdf

Comment: @Nicola, thanks. That's very interesting! But in general it is integrable only in a generalized sense: some integral curves may terminate, that is, they are no longer inextensible in the manifold.

Comment: Well integrable to me means to me each point is contained in a maximal integral submanifold, which does not imply each "Hamiltonian" flow can be indefinitely extended. This happens also for the symplectic foliation of Poisson manifolds.

Comment: What can we say about tarjectories?

Comment: Hassan, it's possible you're missing the connection. When the dimension of $\ker \omega$ is larger than 1, a leaf of the foliation is the generalization of the $1$-dimensional notion of a trajectory.

Comment: I think it is an interesting problem which foliations can occur in this way. Locally, all nonsingular foliations occur this way, I think, but the types of singularities might not be arbitrary, and the global question, even on surfaces, might be interesting.